# Radio button with defined value always returns "on"

Tags: php, forms

I have a very odd problem... I'm submitting a form with radio buttons (see below) and as you can see, all the buttons have values. And yet, when I try to get the value of the selected button, whichever I have selected, it always returns "on".

I know "on" is the default value for radio buttons, but I did specify a value... so why??

Any insight would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

index.php file:

```
<form  class="needs-validation" action="newuser.php?espace=1" method="POST" name="activity" autocomplete="off">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="usertype" value="1" class="form-check-input" required><label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">Étudiant</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="usertype" value="2" class="form-check-input" required><label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">Personnel de l'université</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio5" name="usertype" value="5" class="form-check-input" required><label class="form-check-label" for="radio5">Professionnel</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio9" name="usertype" value="9" class="form-check-input" required><label class="form-check-label" for="radio9">Particulier</label>
```

newuser.php file:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['prenom'], $_REQUEST['nom'], $_REQUEST['mail'], $_REQUEST['usertype'])) {
  echo $_REQUEST['usertype'];
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. I had a hidden input screwing everything up... Sorry. Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be with `$_REQUEST`. Try switching to `$_POST` (in your specific case)

Comment: I've tried with $_POST as well, but got the same result...

Answer (score 0):

Below you can see how the search string is generated from the form before it is sent to the php script for processing. Admittedly, the search string only makes sense for a GET request. Nonetheless it illustrates, that clearly no "ON" value is sent but instead something like `usertype=5`:

```js
// submit handler de-activated again:
if (false) document.querySelector("form").onsubmit=function(ev){
 ev.preventDefault();
 console.log((new URLSearchParams(new FormData(this))).toString())
}
```

```html
<form  class="needs-validation" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" method="POST" name="activity" autocomplete="off">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="usertype" value="1" class="form-check-input" required><label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">Étudiant</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="usertype" value="2" class="form-check-input" required><label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">Personnel de l'université</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio5" name="usertype" value="5" class="form-check-input" required><label class="form-check-label" for="radio5">Professionnel</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio9" name="usertype" value="9" class="form-check-input" required><label class="form-check-label" for="radio9">Particulier</label>
<button>go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I agree, it should work... but unfortunately it doesn't and I don't understand why. Is there anything that could cause a conflict?

Comment: It is impossible to say without seeing your PHP code. I just changed the snippet again to make it perform an _actual_ post to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users , a public AJAX site for testing. The reply clearly shows only _a single result_ of the form `usertype=5` (the `id=11` part is generated additionally by the back end logic).